# How to copy tables from one HiveContext to another?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

As an exercise to deepen my understanding of Spark, I'd like to copy all the tables available in one HiveContext to another HiveContext instance. I'd like to have a solution for temporary and permanent tables. How can I do it the most idiomatic way?

Comment: unless you store them as tables, i don't see another way around. did you try that approach ? as a matter of fact, I'm having troubles understanding why is there two hivecontexts defined. would you care to clarify that point please ?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: Did you get any solution for this?